# Python FAQ: “How fast are exceptions?”

Tags: python, performance, exception, try-catch

I was just looking at the Python FAQ because it was mentioned in another question. Having never really looked at it in detail before, I came across [this question](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-fast-are-exceptions): “How fast are exceptions?”:

> A try/except block is extremely efficient. Actually catching an exception is expensive. In versions of Python prior to 2.0 it was common to use this idiom:
>
> ```
> try:
>     value = mydict[key]
> except KeyError:
>     mydict[key] = getvalue(key)
>     value = mydict[key]
> ```

I was a little bit surprised about the *“catching an exception is expensive”* part. Is this referring only to those `except` cases where you actually save the exception in a variable, or generally all `except`s (including the one in the example above)?

I’ve always thought that using such idioms as shown would be very pythonic, especially as in Python *“it is Easier to Ask Forgiveness than it is to get Permission”*. Also many answers on SO generally follow this idea.

Is the performance for catching Exceptions really that bad? Should one rather follow LBYL (“Look before you leap”) in such cases?

*(Note that I’m not directly talking about the example from the FAQ; there are many other examples where you just look out for an exception instead of checking the types before.)*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Catching exceptions *is* expensive, but exceptions should be *exceptional* (read, not happen very often).  If exceptions are rare, `try/catch` is faster than LBYL.

The following example times a dictionary key lookup using exceptions and LBYL when the key exists and when it doesn't exist:

```
import timeit

s = []

s.append('''\
try:
    x = D['key']
except KeyError:
    x = None
''')

s.append('''\
x = D['key'] if 'key' in D else None
''')

s.append('''\
try:
    x = D['xxx']
except KeyError:
    x = None
''')

s.append('''\
x = D['xxx'] if 'xxx' in D else None
''')

for i,c in enumerate(s,1):
    t = timeit.Timer(c,"D={'key':'value'}")
    print('Run',i,'=',min(t.repeat()))
```

#### Output

```
Run 1 = 0.05600167960596991       # try/catch, key exists
Run 2 = 0.08530091918578364       # LBYL, key exists (slower)
Run 3 = 0.3486251291120652        # try/catch, key doesn't exist (MUCH slower)
Run 4 = 0.050621117060586585      # LBYL, key doesn't exist
```

When the usual case is no exception, `try/catch` is "extremely efficient" when compared to LBYL.

Comment: Pretty much what I was going to say. It's using exceptions to control your normal program flow that's really expensive.

Comment: Doing some quick math, the numbers indicate try/except should only be used if you expect the key won't be found at most 8.95% of time (about 1 in 11 calls). I don't have room to derive the equation I used but: let `cbn` = cost of branching method in normal case, `cbx` = cost of branch method in exceptional case, `ctn` = cost of try/except in normal case, `ctx` = cost of try/except in exceptional case, and px = probability of exceptional case occurring; then for all `px <= (ctn-cbn)/(ctn-ctx+cbx-cbn)`, the try/except method will be faster in the long term.

Comment: Just an addendum - since measuring and calculating these sorts of things tends to get time-consuming in itself, I try to use a rule of thumb for python that anything which occurs more than 1/8 times is not an "exceptional" case, and should probably use another method - which has also proved useful when designing an api, as well as writing code.

Comment: "exceptions should be exceptional" is a good mantra.  I forget it too often.

Answer (score 6):

The cost depends on implementation, obviously, but I wouldn't worry about it. It's unlikely going to matter, anyway. Standard protocols raise exceptions in strangest of places (think `StopIteration`), so you're surrounded with raising and catching whether you like it or not.

When choosing between LBYL and EAFP, worry about readability of the code, instead of focusing on micro-optimisations. I'd avoid type-checking if possible, as it might reduce the generality of the code.

Comment: Yes, avoid premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

If the case where the key is not found is more than exceptional, I would suggest using the 'get' method, which provide a constant speed in all cases :

```
s.append('''\
x = D.get('key', None)
''')

s.append('''\
x = D.get('xxx', None)
''')
```

Comment: You can use `dict.setdefault` instead. But then again, the code was just a simple example from the FAQ.