# Create set and lists with the positions in the set efficently

Tags: python, dictionary

I need create a set of the IDs of some messages, and the positions in the original list. The code is used to sort the messages an later handle them according to ID.

The following works, is readable, but slow.

```
import numpy as np
IDs=np.array([354,45,45,34,354])#example, the actual array is huge

Dict={}
for counter in xrange(len(IDs)):
    try:
        Dict[IDs[counter]].append(counter)
    except:
        Dict[IDs[counter]]=[counter]
print(Dict)
#{354: [0, 4], 34: [3], 45: [1, 2]}
```

Any ideas how to speed it up? There is no need for the lists to be sorted. Later in the code is used as follows, and after that the dict is discarded

```
for item in Dict.values():
    Position_of_ID=Position[np.array(item)]
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutch faster is using a "dictcompression"

```
Dict = {id:i for i, id in enumerate(IDs)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `defaultdict` and `enumerate`:

```
from collections import defaultdict    
Dict = defaultdict(list)
for i,id in enumerate(IDs):
    Dict[id].append(i)
```

(using `try` and `except` is a bad idea [if the exceptions aren't rare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8108440/2069380))

Comment: with my data that saves about a third on execution time, nice.

Comment: But still there must be a way do this without the pure python loop, and probably without using dicts.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest code I came up with, is this. It does much more math, is not as readable, and I am not proud, but it is a lot quicker (even with large arrays):

```
    Sorted_positions_of_IDs=np.argsort(IDs,kind='mergesort')
    SortedIDs=IDs[Sorted_positions_of_IDs]
    Position=0    
    Position_last=-1
    Dict={}
    while(Position<len(Sorted_positions_of_IDs)):
        ID=SortedIDs[Position]
        Position_last=np.searchsorted(SortedIDs,ID,side='right')
        Dict[ID]=Sorted_positions_of_IDs[Position:Position_last]
        Position=Position_last
```

Anyway, good Ideas will be appreciated.