# Overriding __add__, exception not being caught trying super().__add__

Tags: python, inheritance, addition, timedelta

I am trying to subclass pandas' `Timedelta` so when it gets summed by a integer/float, we consider it as a `Timedelta` with seconds.

I tried the following:

```
class Timedelta(pd.Timedelta):
    def __add__(self, other):
        print("OVERRIDEN ADD")
        try:
            print("SUPER ADD")
            return super().__add__(other)
        except:
            print("NEW ADD")
            return super().__add__(Timedelta(str(other)+"s"))
```

But for some reason I can't get it to go to the `"NEW ADD"` implementation:

```
>>> a = Timedelta2('10s')
>>> a+1
OVERRIDEN ADD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
SUPER ADD
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-51-98b939904c8e>", line 1, in <module>
    a+1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timedelta2' and 'int'
```

I was expecting this `TypeError` exception to be caught, but for some reason it isn't, so I would like to ask for some help to figure out what could be happening here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`super().__add__(other)` doesn't raise an exception! It returns `NotImplemented`. That's how you signal that your operator overload doesn't understand the argument it's getting. The `TypeError` comes from the operator machinery once both sides say they can't perform the operation.

Instead of trying to catch an exception that isn't coming from there anyway, check whether `super().__add__(other)` returns `NotImplemented`.

Answer (score 1):

You are no really understand the `__add__` method! try below way to got your expect! `try ... expect` is not efficient, so you should use `if .. else` instead.

```
import pandas as pd

class MyTimedelta(pd.Timedelta):
    def __add__(self, other):
        print("OVERRIDEN ADD")
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return pd.Timedelta("{}s".format(int(self.seconds)+ other))
        else:    
            super(MyTimedelta, self).__add__(other)
```

and then you can do the operation like:

```
In [22]: s=MyTimedelta('2s')

In [23]: s+3
OVERRIDEN ADD
Out[23]: Timedelta('0 days 00:00:05')
```

Comment: What do you mean `try ... except` is not efficient? It is much more efficient than checking the value's type every single time. Try [this](https://pastebin.com/Am0HLcpu).

Comment: Relevant question: [Python FAQ: “How fast are exceptions?”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8107695/216074)